# Is there a `net` view like command?

Tags: software-recommendation, command-line

`net` is a windows command line tool that can do a lot of stuff around networking. If you add an argument like `view` to the `net` command(`new view`) it will search everything in your network.

Is there a command for Linux that can search everything in your network users and such?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `smbtree` - a text based smb network browser.

Example:

```
smbtree -N
WORKGROUP
    \\S160P1                
        \\S160P1\C$
        \\S160P1\ADMIN$
        \\S160P1\IPC$
[...]
```